# Use JOOQ to do a delete specifying multiple columns in a "not in" clause

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I want to bring a postgres database table in sync with a list of Jooq Records.

I have a table with a composite primary key and three other values in each row

```
table(k1, k2, v1, v2, v3)
```

For example, the data might be

```
Last, First, Age, Weight, Height
Smith, Joe,  21,  75,     160
Jones, Pete, 23,  80,     180
```

(excuse the poor form of using names as primary keys....)

I also have a list of Jooq Records for that table in my java code. Let's say that there's two java records

```
[
   <Smith, Joe, 21, 75, 180>,
   <Taylor, Mark, 54, 90, 170> 
]
```

What I would want to happen is when I run some code,

- The database row for Joe Smith has it's height updated
- A new row is inserted for Mark Taylor
- The database row for Pete Jones is deleted

I have managed to create a function that does the first two parts, but am stuck on the third. I was hoping to have a pretty simple "one liner" in JOOQ that basically did

```
delete 
from my_table 
where (first, last) not in (values ('Joe', 'Smith'), ('Mark', 'Taylor'))
```

but I can't work out the corresponding Java code to do it.

Are there any Jooq-masters reading this?

Is there an obvious thing I'm over-looking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your query can be translated to the following jOOQ code:

```java
// Assuming this:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

using(configuration)
   .deleteFrom(MY_TABLE)
   .where(row(MY_TABLE.FIRST, MY_TABLE.LAST).notIn(
        row("Joe", "Smith"),
        row("Mark", "Taylor")
   ))
   .execute();
```

This is using [`DSL.row()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#row-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-) to construct row value expressions. Note that `ROW` is an optional keyword in PostgreSQL. You just happened to omit it in your SQL example.

See also the manual's section about the `IN` predicate for degrees > 1:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate-degree-n

Comment: Thanks Lukas, yet again!

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to just delete on a primary key and a good practice as you said. As long as there are no two people called pete jones, something like this should work:

```
dsl.deleteFrom(MY_TABLE)
 .where(MY_TABLE.first.eq("pete").and(MY_TABLE.last.eq("jones")).execute();
```