# Querying a composite key with multiple IN values with jOOQ

Tags: jooq, predicate, composite-key

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (id, other_id, status)
IN (
    (1, 'XYZ', 'OK'),
    (2, 'ZXY', 'OK') -- , ...
);
```

Is it possible to construct this query in a type-safe manner using `jOOQ`, preferably without generating composite keys? Is it possible to do this using `jOOQ 3.11`?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60730924/521799

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64497417/521799) already shows how to do this with a 1:1 translation from SQL to jOOQ using the [IN predicate for degrees > 1](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate-degree-n/).

Starting from jOOQ 3.14, there is also the option of using the new [`<embeddablePrimaryKeys/>`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-embeddable-types/codegen-embedded-keys/) flag in the code generator, which will produce embeddable types for all primary keys (and foreign keys referencing them). This will help never forget a key column on these queries, which is especially useful for joins.

Your query would look like this:

```java
ctx.selectFrom(TABLE)
   .where(TABLE.PK_NAME.in(
      new PkNameRecord(1, "XYZ", "OK"), 
      new PkNameRecord(2, "ZXY", "OK")))
   .fetch();
```

The query generated behind the scenes is the same as yours, using the 3 constraint columns for the predicate. If you add or remove a constraint from the key, the query will no longer compile. A join would look like this:

```java
ctx.select()
   .from(TABLE)
   .join(OTHER_TABLE)
   .on(TABLE.PK_NAME.eq(OTHER_TABLE.FK_NAME))
   .fetch();
```

Or an [implicit join](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/) would look like this:

```java
ctx.select(OTHER_TABLE.table().fields(), OTHER_TABLE.fields())
   .from(OTHER_TABLE)
   .fetch();
```

Answer (score 4):

My apologies, it seems my Google-fu was not up to par. The opposite of this question can be found here: [Use JOOQ to do a delete specifying multiple columns in a "not in" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213470/use-jooq-to-do-a-delete-specifying-multiple-columns-in-a-not-in-clause)

For completeness' sake, so that other Google searches might be more immediately helpful, the solution is:

```java
// can be populated using DSL.row(...); for each entry
Collection<? extends Row3<Long, String, String>> values = ... 

dslContext.selectFrom(TABLE)
 .where(DSL.row(ID, OTHER_ID, STATUS).in(values))
 .fetch();
```

Relevant `jOOQ` documentation: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate-degree-n/